# Using Gaussian elimination to solve 3x3 matrix with unknown.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

[image: Matrix in question]

I'm trying to find values for k, such that the set of equations(Ax=b) have i)one solution, ii)infinite solutions and iii) no solutions.

All I can think of is dividing rows 1 and 3 by  the number 2, and then perhaps subtracting row 1 from row 3.

I've been stuck for a while and have been making no progress.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you heard about determinants?

Comment: @Arthur: determinants aren't need for Gaussian elimination !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I missed that the title said we should use GE. I think determinants would give a quicker answer to this question, though.

Comment: @Arthur: Cramer will require the evaluation of $4$ $3\times3$ determinants, each made of $6$ terms (triple products). Gaussian elimination is simpler (this case can be solved mentally with a handful of operations). As of the fourth order, determinants are to be banned.

Comment: @YvesDaoust We're not trying to find solutions, but rather the _number_ of solutions. That just means setting the determinant to $0$ and solve. Of course, to differentiate between no solutions and infinitely many, we need to do something, so maybe it's not faster after all.

Comment: @Arthur: Gaussian elimination obviously also faster for that task. I wonder where you can get this wrong idea from.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract half of the first equation from the third to get a zero bottom left.

Swap the second and third equations (to get a constant in the middle).

Subtract $k$ times the second from the third.

Now you have an echelon form, which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we get
$$x_1=1-x_2$$ plugging this in the third equation we get $$kx_3=1$$
if $k=0$ then we have no Solutions, if $$k\neq0$$ then we get
$$x_3=\frac{1}{k_3}$$
Can you finish?